# Length of optimal play in Hex as a function of size

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, percolation

Consider Hex on an $n \times n$ board without a swap rule, so that the first player wins.  Assume the first player tries to minimize the length of the game, and the second player tries to maximize the length.  Call the resulting optimal length $f(n)$.

**Question:** What are the asymptotics of $f(n)$?

Trivially $f$ is at least linear and at most quadratic.  [Campbell, On optimal play in the game of Hex](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.532.5545&rep=rep1&type=pdf) give a linear lower bound with constant 2.5 (as opposed to 2 if the second player helps the first to win).

Are there better bounds on $f(n)$, or conjectured bounds?  I would expect it to be superlinear, but don’t know if it’s subquadratic.  An intermediate exponent would be quite interesting.

**Update**: [Peres et al., Random-Turn Hex and other selection games](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508580) estimate the exponent for the variant of Hex where the player to move is random per turn at between 1.5 and 1.6.  That is, they conjecture that the optimal length in random turn Hex is between $O(n^{1.5})$ and $O(n^{1.6})$.  Unclear how this corresponds to the original Hex game.  Figure from the paper:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[HexWiki](https://www.hexwiki.net/index.php/Basic_(strategy_guide)#Board_size) says a typical (human) game fills roughly 1/3 of the board, but people probably resign when a virtual connection is formed or earlier.

If you want to do some empirical study, there is [a version of KataGo](https://www.hexwiki.net/index.php/KataHex) modified for Hex by HZY, and KataGo allows training networks that work for multiple board sizes, but I don't know if the code uses the number of moves as an auxiliary target in addition to winning. Networks trained on up to 27x27 board are available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VfWL1MUOCSQo78KdgEkF7roErRl-Wjhp/view) (together with GUI) and the code is [here](https://github.com/hzyhhzy/KataGo/tree/Hex2022), but apparently HZY has started working on [an update](https://github.com/hzyhhzy/KataGo/tree/Hex2024).

Even though all 9x9 openings and two [10x10](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ehayward/talks/hex.sol10.pdf) [openings](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ehayward/396/hoven/8hex.pdf) are solved (from 2013; any updates?), the solutions probably optimize the number of steps to a virtual connection (e.g. consisting of templates) rather than to an actual connection; but maybe this is close enough.

(Curiously I arrived at this question by searching "percolation theory" and "Hex". I saw HZY's empirical study of the winrates of openings [on Zhihu](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/476464087), and wonder whether there's a percolation theoretic explanation of the observed pattern, and whether one can exhibit a winning first move on every (large enough?) board and prove it's winning; because there's always a winner, one only needs to show it's "at least as good" as all other moves. Let me mention that there's a explicit (polynomial time) [winning strategy](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ehayward/papers/handicap.pdf) that starts with two stones on boards up to 10x10, three stones on boards up to 16x16, and so on. Moore and Shannon's resistor network is used in programs like Hexy as an evaluation function, and apparently there are papers that study resistor networks from a percolation theory perspective.)